# Are there any recent resources on the Keres Defense?

Tags: opening

I am changing my Black repertoire, and became interested in the variation:

1. d4 e6
2. c4 Bb4+.

I wonder if there are any recent resources about this "Keres defense" to learn some plans and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enter the position into the [free Lichess analysis board](https://lichess.org/analysis) or another board of your choice to see what the engine recommends and also to see what top players played in the opening.

As for books, I believe [this one](https://discoverbooks.com/products/openings-by-computer-vol1-the-kangaroo-defense-the-kangaroo-defense-1481153943) to be good (it is called the Kangaroo defence here but it's the same opening).

It is expensive on the website I listed but you can probably find it cheaper elsewhere.